# How to setup a basic manytomany relationship with JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a very basic many to many relationship: Persons and Projects, set up as follows:

Person:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "person_project", 
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Person_Id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Project_id"))
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<Project>();
```

Project:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "person_project", 
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Project_Id"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Person_id"))
private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
```

When updating a Person, new projects may be specified. I have a JPARepository set up for Person and I use saveAndFlush(...) to save the possible new Projects with the Person.

This works for one Person. If I add a new Project it will be saved with the Person and the tables in the database update correctly. However, If I then add the same Project for another Person - it will be deleted from the first Person! The id of the first person is replaced with the id of the second person in the join table.

What causes this? is my relation setup incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use the same annotation on both halves of the mapping.  The first part defines the join tables and columns.  The second half of the mapping only needs to know the name of the other half (projects in your case), it will get the details from the first annotation.  For a decent explaination see: [Hibernate Many to Many Mapping](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/)

Comment: Interesting. I got the idea from the Pro Spring 3 Book's examples where it was indeed done this way: same mapping on both sides with just the columns swapped. I cannot find a similar example online, but I did find several pages mentioning that "mappedBy" is needed for bidirectional relations and that unidirectional relations would have no annotations on the inverse side. I remain slightly confused.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like changing Project as follows fixes the problem:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="projects")
private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
```

Now when I add the same project to a second person, the first one will remain related to that project as it should.

I still don't know why this works, so If someone can explain it, please do!

Comment: Do you know the problem? Can you explain?

Comment: Nope, I have no better explanation than the one given in the answer by @WPrecht